# How to enable footer in MS Dynamics AX's Form

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a little problem, how to show the footer just like below? is it possible from the code or from the properties? thanks beforehand.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The footer is a status bar.

It is controlled by the `StatusBarStyle` property of the design node.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa857335.aspx):

> Determines how to display the status bar on a form. Use this property
>   to hide the status bar, display only help information, display status
>   bar elements based on the WindowType, or to always display the full
>   status bar. Forms with a WindowType of ListPage, ContentPage, or
>   Workspace ignore this property.

When set to `Auto` it looks at the `WindowType` to infer the value. Lookups do not have status bar etc.